# Query to subtract the column value from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the below output with the following query.

```
SELECT TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST,SHIPMENT_GID, PERSPECTIVE
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE SHIPMENT_GID IN
   (SELECT SHIPMENT_GID FROM SHIPMENT_STOP_D
    WHERE S_SHIP_UNIT_GID IN
        (SELECT S_SHIP_UNIT_GID FROM S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE
         WHERE ORDER_RELEASE_GID LIKE :ORDER_RELEASE_ID))
```

When I pass the Order_Release_ID as CT/PLI.KIKO3 I get the output as below.

I want a field as profit that would be  (total actual cost where perspective is 'S' - total actual cost where perspective is 'B') ie in the above case it would be (5980 -1020 = 4960)

Please let me know what changes I need to make in the above query to get the profit field.

Here what I actually want is to subtract the column values from the same table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` as following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN PERSPECTIVE = 'S' THEN TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST
    END) - SUM(CASE
        WHEN PERSPECTIVE = 'B' THEN TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST
    END) AS PROFIT,
    SHIPMENT_GID, 
    --PERSPECTIVE, 
    ORDER_RELEASE_ID
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE SHIPMENT_GID IN
   (SELECT SHIPMENT_GID FROM SHIPMENT_STOP_D
    WHERE S_SHIP_UNIT_GID IN
        (SELECT S_SHIP_UNIT_GID FROM S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE
         WHERE ORDER_RELEASE_GID LIKE :ORDER_RELEASE_ID))
GROUP BY SHIPMENT_GID, ORDER_RELEASE_ID
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
/* here goes your initial query from the question */
WITH src AS (SELECT TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST,SHIPMENT_GID, PERSPECTIVE
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE SHIPMENT_GID IN (SELECT SHIPMENT_GID 
FROM SHIPMENT_STOP_D
WHERE S_SHIP_UNIT_GID IN
(SELECT S_SHIP_UNIT_GID FROM S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE
WHERE ORDER_RELEASE_GID LIKE :ORDER_RELEASE_ID))

select src_s.total_actual_cost - src_b.total_actual_cost
/* here any other fields you need */
from src src_b,
src src_s
where src_s.order_release_id = src_b.order_release_id
and src_b.PERSPECTIVE = 'B'
and src_s.PERSPECTIVE = 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I'm a fan of nested `IN` logic, so I would be inclined to write this using `JOIN` and `EXISTS`.

Then, if you want one row per `ORDER_RELEASE_ID`, then conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.ORDER_RELEASE_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Perspective = 'S' THEN s.TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST
                WHEN s.Perspective = 'B' THEN - s.SHIPMENT_GID
           END) as Profit
FROM SHIPMENT s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SHIPMENT_STOP_D ss JOIN
                   S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE sul
                   USING (S_SHIP_UNIT_GID)
              WHERE s.SHIPMENT_GID = ss.SHIPMENT_GID AND
                    sul.ORDER_RELEASE_GID LIKE :ORDER_RELEASE_ID
             )
GROUP BY s.ORDER_RELEASE_ID;
```

If you want the original rows along with an additional "profit" columns, then use analytic functions:

```
SELECT s.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Perspective = 'S' THEN s.TOTAL_ACTUAL_COST
                WHEN s.Perspective = 'B' THEN - s.SHIPMENT_GID
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.ORDER_RELEASE_ID) as Profit
FROM SHIPMENT s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SHIPMENT_STOP_D ss JOIN
                   S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE sul
                   USING (S_SHIP_UNIT_GID)
              WHERE s.SHIPMENT_GID = ss.SHIPMENT_GID AND
                    sul.ORDER_RELEASE_GID LIKE :ORDER_RELEASE_ID
             );
```